# SignalR across domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I'm trying to get a basic sample across domains working, but I just cannot get it to work. According to someone here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/6 he got it to work by adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Basically, I've added a hub to an mvc 3 application, added the above header in the web.config, and created a page to send a message. This setup works fine.
Next, I've created a different web application using the same client javascript on a page, but setting the url to a different server using:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://www.myserver.com/signalr';
```

As soon as I use a remote url it stops working.

How can I get SignalR to work across domains?

Update:
Some added information, the above approach works for chrome and firefox, but IE9 is not liking it...

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? Not all browsers support the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: I've been using IE9 and Chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working using a simple test project and Internet Explorer 9, but it wasn't easy and first I was hung on the same problems you described. I think you are almost there and you are only missing the following line in your JavaScript:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

which tells jQuery to do cross domain calls. Seems simple, but was really hard to find ;-)

I explained all the steps I did in a [blog post](http://coding4life.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/making-cross-domain-calls-in-signalr/) since I didn't find any existing information on this topic so far.

Tell me if there are any more problems. I have a working test project running in Internet Explorer 9 which I can send you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It does throw an access denied exception in the background on the forever frame (var $ = window.parent.jQuery to be exact), and the user gets a popup message to allow cors, but it sends and receives the messages!

Comment: Weird, I didn't get any popup message... Is this in IE or another browser? Glad it works :-)

Comment: This is in IE9 indeed. I hope they get official cross domain support soon in SignalR :)

Comment: This blog post is spot on mate, saved me a LOT of hassle! Thank you.